# "Attempting to reconnect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://localhost:9200)) with 3 reconnect attempt(s)" error appears

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I am running filebeat, elastic search and kibana to get logs of nginx from local machine, i am directly connecting filebeat with elastic search in filebeat configuration but as i start filebeat config , it shows errors like"    pipeline/output.go:145  Attempting to reconnect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://localhost:9200)) with 3 reconnect attempt(s)" and no logs received by kibana.

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200` in a terminal on that machine?

Comment: {
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 7,
  "active_shards" : 7,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 5,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 58.333333333333336
}

Comment: Can you update your question with your Filebeat logs when it starts?

Comment: I got that its an issue with version conflict, my filebeat version is 7.9.2, and elastic search is 6.8 so for now i am upgrading it to 7.9.2

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out! You should write that as an answer, so future readers know about it.

Comment: Thanks but i am not sure about that as its going on for installation right now

Comment: It's gonna work for sure!

Comment: you can add following in filebeat.yml file:
allow_older_versions: true